# unwanted asynchronous event dispatching

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I code a 'attributes setting' window with jqxWidgets (slider, color control) in order to set visual object attributes (color, border width, etc.)
On each jqxWidget, I declare a function in order to detect change and to apply this change on visual object.
So, when object is selected with mouse, I disable the callback :

`$('#width').on('change', undefined);`

Then I force the jqxWidget to object value :

`$('#width').jqxSlider('setValue', object.width);`

Then I enabled event trigger :

`$('#width').on('change', the_width_on_change_callback);`

But It seems that asynchronous mechanism does enable the event trigger before the value is forced, so the `the_width_on_change_callback` function is called.
Using global flag in order to filter doesn't work; How to solve this ?
Best regards.

Comment: `$('#width').on('change', undefined);` does not remove previously set listeners

Comment: I have found a suggest based on adding or removing a class, like 'enabled'. Is is a good way ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this solution which works well:

```
// on selection
$('#node_label')[0].classList.remove('enabled');
// force widget value
$('#node_label').jqxInput('val', node.label );
// enable event processing
$('#node_label')[0].classList.add('enabled');
```

and in call back function :

```
$('#node_label').on('change', this.on_change_node_label);
```

...

```
this.on_change_node_label = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( ! this.classList.contains('enabled')) return;
    var value = $('#node_label').val();
    }
```